# WebLogic 10gR3 - UnsupportedEncodingException parsing Content-Type header for multipart/form-data

Tags: java, weblogic, content-type, weblogic-10.x, multipartform-data

My application is receiving multi-part content through an HTTP POST, on WebLogic 10gR3. Whenever clients specify the `charset` attribute **before** other attributes on the Content-Type header (e.g. `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=a_random_boundary`), WebLogic is throwing the following exception (caught in my managed server's log):

> Unsupported encoding: "utf-8; boundary=a_random_boundary" specified.
>   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Unsupported Encoding utf-8; boundary=a_random_boundary
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.setCharacterEncoding(ServletRequestImpl.java:428)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.initRequestEncoding(ServletRequestImpl.java:1115)
>           at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.getCharacterEncoding(ServletRequestImpl.java:451)
>           at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getCharacterEncoding(ServletRequestWrapper.java:115)
>           at com.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:100)

Just for information, I am doing a `getCharacterEncoding()` call to an `HttpServletRequest` instance at line 100.

However, if clients specify the charset at the end of the header (e.g. Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a_random_boundary; charset=utf-8), the application and WebLogic perform gracefully.

According to [RFC2045](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt), the order of the parameters is not significant:

> The Content-Type header field specifies the nature of the data in the
>      body of an entity by giving media type and subtype identifiers, and
>      by providing auxiliary information that may be required for certain
>      media types.  After the media type and subtype names, the remainder
>      of the header field is simply a set of parameters, specified in an
>      attribute=value notation.  **The ordering of parameters is not
>      significant**.

I have searched around, and the closer I got to a similar problem was the following [thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=863225) at OTN.

I am assuming this is a bug in WebLogic, but I thought I would look for some insight before contacting support and/or making a workaround.

Thanks for any insight into this issue.

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? I'm not sure that there's any useful answer that could be given at this point.

Comment: @col6y I didn't find any answers for this issue. I think there is value in leaving the question open, so others with the same problem can at least benefit of the initial investigation. Why the downvote, anyway?

Comment: Oops. I interpreted the last part of this post as "I'm going to contact support, so this will quickly become irrelevant once this gets fixed, but before I do is there anything that I'm missing?" (I'd remove the downvote, but it won't let me unless the post gets edited. If you wanted to make a meaningful edit, the line with Content-Type could be in backquotes to be formatted properly.)

Comment: I have done it, but if you feel it is a poor question, nevermind about the downvote. Thanks!

Comment: My previous interpretation was incorrect and don't think this deserves a downvote anymore. I've removed the downvote. Sorry about that.